# How to define an object with variable number of keys and with keys from an enum?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Well, when I started with Angular I came in touch with Typescript the first time - and I did a huge mistake: I used always `any` as datatype.
So now I have a few 10.000 lines of code and want to make it "type-save". Better late then never... and here comes the problem:

I have an object that has a property `validity` with a variable number of key-values, like

```
obj.validity = { 
    time: true,
    feePayed: true,
    approved: true
}
```

or

```
obj.validity = { 
    time: true,
    feePayed: true,
}
```

or

```
obj.validity = { 
    startpass: true,
    passport: true
}
```

the possible keys are defined in an `enum`:

```
export enum VerificationType {
    TIME = 'time',
    STARTPASS = 'startpass',
    PASSPORT = 'passport',
    FEEPAYED = 'feePayed',
    ALLOWPAYPENT = 'allowPayment',
    MANUALRELEASEPAYMENT = 'manualReleasePayment',
    MANUALAPPROVE = 'manualApprove',
    ALLPAYED = 'allPayed',
    APPROVED = 'approved',
}
```

In the object declaration I tried now something like that:

```
class obj {
    validity: ISkaterValidation
}
```

and

```
export type ISkaterValidation = {
    [key in VerificationType]: boolean;
};
```

This fails with `error TS2339: Property 'ANY PROPERTY NAME' does not exist on type 'ISkaterValidation'.`

I'm still a beginner with Typescript typings and hope that somebody can give me a solution, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your type expects every key inside the object. You need to make it optional:

```
export type ISkaterValidation = {
    [key in VerificationType]?: boolean;
};
```

That tells TypeScript that the key doesn't have to exist on the type, but also no other key should be there.